# Use JWT with TurboGears2

Tags: python, rest, jwt, turbogears

I'm currently stopped in my work because of some authentication work on a project.
I set up a **REST** API, which needs to have a **JWT** authentication system.
Some work was already done and I overrode it. So the library used was Python's TurboGears2, and I used **PyJWT** to manage tokens.

My WS and the token's creation works well. The post method with auth info JSON request's body can create a token, that's sent in the response.
But after that, when I do a '**GET**' request on the restricted resource, I can't retrieve the token.

What I do: send a GET request to the restricted resource, with "**Authorization**: Bearer <**TOKEN**>" in request headers.

But when I do a 'request.authorization' in my web service function, I always get 'None'.
Do I need to set up a full auth system using TurboGears to access this header?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to access the `request.authorization` from?

I tried with a newly quickstarted application and modified the index to print the authorization header:

```
@expose('testauth.templates.index')
def index(self):
    """Handle the front-page."""
    print(request.authorization)
    return dict(page='index')
```

And I sent the authorization header from `Postman`.

It worked fine and printed my test header

```
Authorization(authtype='Bearer', params='HELLO')
```

I also tried to disable any `auth_backend` so that authentication is disabled and it still works as expected.